# How to play back images at high speed using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

You are playing a video using [FFmpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer)
. You can play normal, but are there options for fast playback and slow playback?

Comment: How are you playing the video?

Comment: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer
Play this video using this library.

Comment: That is a wrapper. You should open an issue at the project.

Comment: you could use ExoPlayer, it is easier to use than FFmpegMediaPlayer and takes up less space